# Play 2.1 Json Writes for Option Tuple

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.1

I am using Play 2.1 and MongoJack to create a scala class for Mongo db mapping as well as Json serialization. I want to have a option tuple in this model (see "upload" below). However, I can't get the Json Writes working for the option tuple.

```
class Event (
  @BeanProperty @JsonProperty("name") val name: String,
  @BeanProperty @JsonProperty("message") val message: String
  ) {
  @ObjectId @Id @BeanProperty var eventId: String = _
  @BeanProperty @JsonProperty("upload") var upload: Option[(String, String, Int)] =  _
}

object Event {
  def apply(name: String,
         message: String): Event = new Event(name,message)

  def unapply(e: Event) = 
    new Some((e.name,
              e.message,
              e.upload) )

  import play.api.libs.json.Writes._
  val eventWrites: Writes[Event] = (
    (__ \ 'name).write[String] and
    (__ \ 'message).write[String] and
    (__ \ 'upload).write(Option[( // HOW TO WRITE A OPTIONAL TUPLE?
      (__ \ 'url).write[String] and
      (__ \ 'name).write[String] and
      (__ \ 'size).write[Int]
      tupled
    )])
    )(unlift(Event.unapply))
}
```

> EDIT 1:

Replace upload initial value with

```
@BeanProperty @JsonProperty("upload") var upload: Option[(String, String, Int)] =  None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your writes would look like this:

```
val eventWrites: Writes[Event] = (
  (__ \ 'name).write[String] and
  (__ \ 'message).write[String] and
  (__ \ 'upload).writeNullable((
    (__ \ 'url).write[String] and
    (__ \ 'name).write[String] and
    (__ \ 'size).write[Int]).tupled))(unlift(Event.unapply))
```

You don't need to import `Writes._`

Comment: Thank you! It works. Also, I have to change upload's init value to None.